# display word document to browser with php

Tags: php

This is the function I have tried, but its not displaying any content.  I am pulling this content from a database and getting everything I need but the actual document content.

```
 private function read_docx(){
//var_dump($this-filename);
    $striped_content = '';
    $content = '';

    $zip = zip_open($this->filename);

    if (!$zip || is_numeric($zip)) return false;

    while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {

        if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry) == FALSE) continue;

        if (zip_entry_name($zip_entry) != "word/document.xml") continue;

        $content .= zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));

        zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
    }// end while

    zip_close($zip);

    $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc>', " ", $content);
    $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p>', "\r\n", $content);
    $striped_content = strip_tags($content);

    return $striped_content;
}
```

This where i display the content, but it shows up empty.

```
$document = new DocxConversion($name['name']);
            $reflector = new ReflectionObject($document);
            $method = $reflector->getMethod('read_docx');
            $method->setAccessible(true);
            echo $method->invoke($document) . "<br>";
            //$newDoc = $document->read_docx();
            echo $name['name'] . "<br>";
            echo $extension . "<br>";
```

Comment: I got the document, but the formatting is gone.  anyone have any suggestions beside phpword library.  I would like to use the xmlParser, but not sure where to start.

Comment: I used to use this API: https://www.zoho.com/writer/